# Сортировка по дате из строки. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, дата, datetime

В таблице есть поле "Номер фактуры" вида **AB/dd/mm/yyyy**

Нужно отсортировать строки по этому полю в порядке возрастания, взяв за основу только дату "**01/01/2000**"

> AB/01/01/2000 .. AB/31/12/2010

стандартной конструкцией mysql отсортировал так
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZB46.png

-- 09/09, 01/09, 10/09

Что неправильно. Как без процедур отсортировать именно так как задумывалось?

Comment: Нужно добавить вычисляемое поле на основе ваших данных, содержащее дату в правильном формате и сортировать по этому полю

Comment: Если использование даты, извлечённой из поля номера - частая операция, разумнее добавить в структуру таблицы вычисляемое поле ([Generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)), формирующее дату из этого значения. Возможно, хранимое.

Answer (score 3):

Можно вот так, превращая `AB/31/12/2010` в `20101231`. Такой текстовый формат yyyymmdd правильно сортируется без перевода в дату

```
order by concat(substr(field_name, 10,4), substr(field_name, 7,2), substr(field_name, 4,2))
```

Comment: Верно работает только при фиксированном количестве символов на поле. Иначе надо использовать SUBSTRING_INDEX().

Comment: Да. Но в вопросе так спрашивалось. Если не нужно, то чего городить еще более сложное выражение :).

Comment: Не, я так, на всякий случай. Вдруг кто ещё столкнётся с подобно задачей, воспользуется поиском, найдёт эту тему, и вроде решение есть, а в его частном случае не стрельнёт.

Comment: Это да, согласен